# Same code compiled with different versions provides different result

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am using an external library which I do not control nor know the internals (lets call it proprietarycallbacks).

I know that I have a class called callbacks that has two bool variables:

```
class callbacks : public proprietarycallbacks {
  bool a = false;
  bool b = false;
  virtual callbackHandler() {
    cout "callback received\n";
    b = true;
  }
}
```

then I have another class which inherits from the callbacks class:

```
class MyObject : public callbacks {

  void test() {
    while (!b) {
      cout << "test " << a << " " << b << endl;
      usleep(100000);
    }
  }
}
```

This code compiles correctly in two different linux versions, with two different GCC versions and LIBC versions.

On the most recent one (linux mint, GCC 5.4 LIBC 2.23), I run the app, see the cout in the while and when the callback is called, the code exists the while.

On the older one (debian, GCC 4.9.2, LIBC 2.19), the while never exists, the variable is always false, even though I can see the print from inside the callback.

Is there something wrong with the way I am structuring the code, and the variable inheritance, or does this have something to do with the software versions I am using?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Is the setting of `b` and the testing of `a` a typo?  Also is the callback and loop on the same thread?

Comment: If you change your variables to `std::atomic_bool`, does the difference disappear?

Comment: (assuming the aforementioned typo is, in fact, a typo) Supposing `test()` and `callbackHandler()` are called from different threads, you would be doing concurrent read and write to `a`, which, in short, is not guaranteed to work as expected. You could see what happens with `std::atomic_bool`, as suggested, or even just declaring `a` to be `volatile`; it is very possible that one compiler version decides that `a` is not changing in the loop and keeps reading it from e.g. a register instead of memory.

Comment: @jdehesa `volatile` is not for solving threading problems.

Comment: @RichardCritten Right, but I think it would make the enough difference in this case to get both compilers to produce programs behave similarly (and reveal why it was not the case before). Of course, it would probably not be enough for the real application.

Comment: @RichardCritten yes its a typo, I will correct it.

Comment: @jdehesa I never used atomic_bool before and I don't know how to declare and initialize atomic_bools. I tried a few options but since I was not sure this was the case, I tried different things. I tried volatile and the issue remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obvious from your `test()` method that there are multiple execution threads involved. `test()` is in one execution thread, and the callbacks get invoked by the other execution thread.

Setting the `bool` flags in the other execution thread, and reading the same flags in the `test()` execution thread are not sequenced with each other.

The usual solution is to either use `std::atomic_bool`; or use a `std::mutex` to implement sequencing, and accessing the variables, either to set them in one execution thread, or read their current values in the other execution thread, only while the mutex is locked.

Comment: can you ellaborate more? I agree that the lack of a mutex means that I can read a variable with an incorrect value, while it is being changed. Nonetheless, on the next while iteration, shouldn't the read had the updated value?

Comment: @BlunT: Why should it ?

Comment: when the read is made while a write is being made, I understand that the value being read is incorrect. But on subsequent reads, shouldn't the value be retrieved from the object, which has been updated in the meanwhile? Why then? Is the value cached for undefined time?

Comment: A C++ compiler is allowed to generate any code that's optimized in any way that does not change observable results. `int a=b+c; int d=b+e;` The C++ compiler is permitted to generate code that reads `b` only once, even though it's used twice. This has no observable changes in the results, since nothing changes the value of `b`. There's nothing in `test()` that changes the observable value of `b`, so the compiler is permitted to generate the code that reads `b` once, if `true` returns from the function, otherwise it enters an infinite loop.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok, in that case, how can I tell the compiler to get its hands out of my code? :) How can I make it re-read the value of those variables everytime?

Comment: I told you already: use a mutex or an atomic variable. That tells the compiler that another execution thread might modify the `bool` at any time. Even if the compiler generates explicit code, unless you're using a single-core CPU, you're still at the whim's of your CPU's multi-core caches. Only explicit sequencing/atomic variables is going to issue special CPU instructions that makes everything happen correctly.